# Returning a Multdimensional Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm looking to have a function return a multidimensional array. The problem is that functions can't return multidimensional array, but they can return pointers. I could return a pointer to a multdimensional array but I'm worried the pointer will become ruined with the function returns.

Instead I'm looking to implement an struct to handle the multidimensional array, but I'm not sure how to initialize the struct and function return type.

Example implementation:

```
struct multiDReturn{
 int* arr;
};

struct multiDReturn someFunction(int a,int b,int c)
{
  int someArr[a][b][c];
  multiDReturn returnArr;
  returnArr.arr = someArr;


}
```

When I try to assign someArr to returnArr.arr I get the error: Incompatible pointer type.

Answer (score 1):

This array

```
int someArr[a][b][c];
```

will go out of scope when `someFunction` returns. So `arr` in `returnArr` will be a dangling pointer.

Also `someArr` is a 3D array not a pointer to `int`. So you can't assign it to `arr`

What you are trying to do will probably look like this :

```
struct multiDReturn {
    int ***arr;
};

struct multiDReturn someFunction(int a, int b, int c) {
    int ***someArr = malloc(a * sizeof (*someArr));
    for (int i = 0; i < a; ++i) {
        someArr[i] = malloc(b * sizeof (**someArr));
        for (int j = 0; j < b; ++j) {
            someArr[i][j] = malloc(c * sizeof (***someArr));
        }
    }
    struct multiDReturn returnArr;
    returnArr.arr = someArr;

    return returnArr;
}
```

and remember to free everything at some point!